# Test class for PageReference method

Tags: visualforce, unit-test, pagereference

Hey I've written a controller for my VF page with a PageReference method. The pagereference is working fine but I'm having some issues with the test class.

Controller class

```
public with sharing class opportunityController{
    public Opportunity opp {get;set;}
    public opportunityController(){
        opp = new Opportunity ();
    }

    public pageReference save(){
        insert opp;
        pagereference page =new ApexPages.StandardController(opp).view();//pageReference ('/apex/OpportunityPage');
        page.setRedirect(true);
        return page;
    }
}
```

Test class

```
@isTest

public class testOpportunityController{
    public static testMethod void testOpp () {
        opportunityController oppC = new opportunityController ();
        Opportunity opp = new Opportunity ();
        pageReference pager = page.OpportunityPage;
        Test.setCurrentPage(pager);
        opp.Name  = 'abc';
        opp.Stagename = 'Prospecting';
        opp.Closedate = system.today();
        insert opp;
        oppC.save();
        apexPages.Currentpage().getParameters().put('Id',opp.id);
   }
}
```

I'm getting an error stating 'Required Fields Missing'. If someone could tell me where I'm going wrong, it'd be great!

Comment: Why are you overriding the existing save method in StandardController instead of just using it on this page for a new opportunity?  It does all the work for you.  Simply use {!save} in an action on your VF, no code necessary, and it redirects automatically.

Comment: I don't understand the point of your code. All it does is save a new opportunity with hardcoded name, stage and today's date, and returns a page reference to it. I think that a standard controller could do that. Nevertheless, if you still want to test this, you need to assert 2 things: that a new opportunity is created, and that the PageReference you get points to its id.

Comment: I was just playing with the custom controller so wanted to test it. And I'm hardcoding the values in the test class and not in the controller class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are missing some required field on opportunity insert. Please check and fill them it is not related to your method.

In class you are creating instance of Opportunity and in your test class you are creating another instance what you need to do here is

```
@isTest

public class testOpportunityController{
    public static testMethod void testOpp () {
        opportunityController oppC = new opportunityController ();
        pageReference pager = page.OpportunityPage;
        Test.setCurrentPage(pager);
        oppC.opp.Name  = 'abc';
        oppC.opp.Stagename = 'Prospecting';
        oppC.opp.Closedate = system.today();
        oppC.save();
       system.assert(oppC.opp.Id != null);

        apexPages.Currentpage().getParameters().put('Id',opp.id);
   }
}
```

Comment: Yeah well those 3 are the only required fields in Opportunity. My error is 'REQUIRED_FIELD_MISSING, Required fields are missing: [Name, StageName, CloseDate]: [Name, StageName, CloseDate]'.

Comment: @User2529 Please check my updated answer.

Comment: Slight correction. It should be         apexPages.Currentpage().getParameters().put('Id',oppC.opp.id); in your code :)

Comment: I don't understand why this tests puts the opportunity's ID in the parameters of the page, or why it edit's oppC.opp to match the values that are already there. IMHO the test should call save() and assert that a new opportunity has been created and that the ID return matches the opp Id.

Answer (score 0):

Your this code is faulty.

```
opp.Name  = 'abc';
opp.Stagename = 'Prospecting';
opp.Closedate = system.today();
insert opp;
```

Check on Opportunity object for all required fields. then populate those fields as well like -

```
opp.requiredField = value
```

then insert the opp. It will work

Comment: Yeah well those 3 are the only required fields in Opportunity. My error is 'REQUIRED_FIELD_MISSING, Required fields are missing: [Name, StageName, CloseDate]: [Name, StageName, CloseDate]'.

Comment: Why are you trying to insert opp in test class when your actual controller is already doing that

Comment: Removed 'insert opp;' if that's what you meant but it's still not working.

Answer (score -1):

There is already an accepted answer, but I'm posting this because I think there is still some untested behaviour.

I assume that your production code is OK and I'm just focusing on the test (which I think should be written first!)

Your controller inserts a new opportunity and returns a page reference with its ID. **Those two actions should be covered by tests**:

```
@isTest
public class testOpportunityController {

    @isTest
    public static testMethod void OpportunityIsInsertedAndPageRefReturned () {
        opportunityController oppC = new opportunityController ();

        Test.startTest();
        pageReference response = oppC.save();
        Test.stopTest();

        System.assert (response != null, 'Expected to have a non null page response');
        String url = response.getUrl;
        System.assert (oppC.opp != null, 'Expected the opportunity in the controller to be non-null');
        String oppID = String.valueOf (oppC.opp.Id);

        system.assertEquals(url, oppId, 'Expected the page reference to contain the opportunity''s Id');

        List<Opportunity> insertedOpps = [Select Id from Opportunity];
        System.AssertEquals (1, insertedOpps.size(), 'Expected to have 1 opportunity in the system');
   }

}
```

I have also done some other improvements:

- Added @isTest to the method (otherwise it will not run as a test!)
- Added a more descriptive name to the test
- Added string to show friendly error messages if assertions fail

There are more cases to test: what happens if you instantiate the controller, override the Opp field (which has a public setter!) and then call save()? What if you override it to null? Those cases are possible, so they must be covered if you want to specify a behaviour for them. Perhaps you want to make the setter private?

Hope you can find some of these comments useful