# Pagereference method not getting called in test class

Tags: visualforce, code-coverage

Here  Job_Role__c,Job_Task__c are the multiselect picklist field which is taking value from variable JobRoles,JobTasks respectively.The issue is the Save() method is not getting called inside test class.
apex class code:--

```
 public Pagereference Save(){
    String JobRoles= '';
    for (String RoleString : selectedRolesMap.keySet()) {
        JobRoles=(JobRoles!=''?JobRoles+';':'')+ selectedRolesMap.get(RoleString);
    }
    String JobTasks= '';
    for (String TaskString : selectedTasksMap.keySet()) {
        if(!TaskString.contains('--None--'))
        JobTasks=(JobTasks!=''?JobTasks+';':'')+ selectedTasksMap.get(TaskString );
    }
    Personnel__c personNew = this.person;

    person.Job_Role__c=JobRoles;
    person.Job_Task__c=JobTasks;
    PageReference detailPage=null;
    try{
      upsert person;
    }
    catch(Exception ex){
      if(ex.getmessage().contains('FIELD_CUSTOM_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION,')){
        Integer result = ex.getmessage().indexOf('FIELD_CUSTOM_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION,', 0);
        System.debug('<<<<<<<<result>>>>>>>>>>> '+result );
        ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.error,ex.getmessage().substring(result + 34,ex.getmessage().length())));
      }
      else{ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.error,ex.getmessage()));} return null;
    }
    string s = '/' + ('' + Person.get('Id')).subString(0, 3) ;
    ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.Severity.Info, s));
    return new Pagereference(s); 

    }
```

test class code:-

```
 ApexPages.StandardController sc = new ApexPages.StandardController(per);
        duplicateedit1 testnew = new duplicateedit1(sc); 
        testnew.Save();
```

Comment: How do you know the Save method is not being executed?  Have you looked at the debug logs?

Comment: @DavidCheng.The save method is not being covered with red part shown in class.\

Answer (score 0):

You can try it in this way

```
  test.startTest();
  PageReference pageRef = Page.yourPageName;
  Test.setCurrentPage(pageRef);
  ApexPages.StandardController sc = new ApexPages.standardController(per);
  duplicateedit1 controller = new duplicateedit1(sc);
  System.assertNotEquals(null,controller.autoRun());
  //System.assertEquals(null,controller.autoRun()); Depenends on your logic
  test.stopTest();
```

basically, the point is to set the pageRef to your current page.

Comment: yes tried that but didnt work

Comment: Is it cover any of the code in save method or will it even not entered in the method.

Comment: you can also take help from the below link, may this be helpful for you.

https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/103178/test-class-for-pagereference-method

Comment: The Save method is not being covered here.That means code is not entering the save method.